# Incorrect value_counts() when using .isin to count matching values in pandas dataframe columns:

Tags: python, pandas

The goal is to iterate through the columns in one table, and find the nearest matching columns in another table.
The end result would be a dataframe containing the percentage overlap for each combination of columns between the 2 dataframes:

|  | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Column 1 | 0.00 | 0 | 0 |
| Column 2 | 1.00 | 0.37 | 0 |
| Column 3 | 1.00 | 0 | 0 |

So 100% of the points in first column in the first dataframe are represented in columns 2&3 of the second dataframe. 37% of the points in the second column of the first dataframe overlap with the second column of the second dataframe. None of the points in the third column of the first dataframe overlap with any of the points in the second dataframe.

Here's an example:

```
    [IN]
    df['t']=2.0
    df['l'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    df['t'].isin(df['l']).value_counts()

    [Out]
    True    6
    Name: t, dtype: int64
```

The result I'm hoping to get is:
True = 1
False = 5

This does appear to work sometimes, for example:

```
    [In]
    df2['a'] = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.01,10.0]
    df2['b'] = [10, 12, 14, 27, 13, 29]
    df2['a'].isin(df2['b']).value_counts()

    [Out]
    False    5
    True     1
    Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Also, I'm aware that switching the code in the first example to be:

`df['l'].isin(df['b']).value_counts()`

would solve the issue, but I'm hoping to iterate through a larger dataframe and do not know in which position the columns will be

Comment: It isn't incorrect. Break down the code. See the output for isin standalone